# Tika isnt reading pdf properly

Tags: html, pdf, apache-tika

I am using Tika to convert pdf files to html and the output is not as expected. The document is 8 pages long and only 2 pages are being read, but they are being repeated in the output. For example it outputs page 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2. The meta data also ouputs:

```
pdf:charsPerPage: 1791
pdf:charsPerPage: 1791
pdf:charsPerPage: 1791
pdf:charsPerPage: 5672
pdf:charsPerPage: 5672
pdf:charsPerPage: 5672
pdf:charsPerPage: 5672
pdf:charsPerPage: 1791
```

What could be happening here? The file in question is publicaly available here: [Phantom_3_Standard_Quick_Start_Guide_en_201509.pdf](http://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/phantom_3_standard/en/Phantom_3_Standard_Quick_Start_Guide_en_201509.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this surprising text extraction result is that the content streams of pages 1, 2, 3, and 8 are very similar, each drawing the content of all four pages, and they only differ in a horizontal shift of coordinates, some clip paths, and minor details.

Basically each of these pages draws all of the following image but hides different, unwanted parts by shifting them out of the page area or using clip paths:

[image: screenshot A]

Also the content streams of page 4-7 are very similar in the same way, basically:

[image: screenshot B]

In particular the text in those sets of four does not differ. Tika apparently ignores whether or not the text it extracts is visible. Thus, you get the same extracted text in those sets of four.

---

<sup>I used [ShowVicinity](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/ShowVicinity.java), a small ad-hoc tool based on PDFBox, to make the whole vicinity of the PDF pages visible.</sup>

Comment: If you'd like to write up a paragraph or so on how to use ShowVicinity to troubleshoot this kind of thing, we'd love to add it to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-PDFTextProblems !

Comment: Currently it is part of a large repository containing lots of stuff not needed to run it. I can try and make it a project of its own with a bit of documentation, but it might take a bit to find the time for that. @Gagravarr, shall I ping you then?

Comment: Just ping us on the Apache Tika dev list - http://tika.apache.org/mail-lists.html - and we'll add it once you're ready!

Comment: Is there any way to detect that this kind of scenario is happening, or have tika ignore the hidden text?

Comment: I don't know which options Tika offers in this regard. Using a pdf library like pdfbox, though, it is easy to implement a check that tests whether there is text outside the page borders.

Comment: @mkl Would you happen to know which feature/area of pdfbox I could reference to perform this check? I wasnt able to figure this out from looking through he docs.

Comment: Pdfbox text extraction usually uses the `PDFTextStripper` class. It has two main methods to override for filtering: `writeText` and `processTextPosition`. In either of those you have to filter the `TextPosition` arguments by the page crop box.

Answer (score 0):

That PDF has an "owner password" set.  You can't extract text from it without the password.

Comment: Would having an owner password cause what I am seeing? I am trying to build a system to convert PDF's and need to eliminate this kind of issue from happening so I need to find a reproducible cause to this issue.

Comment: Are you using PDF tools?  Neither `pdftk` nor `cpdf` nor `pdf2text` are able to decompress this because of the owner password.  People do this to prevent you from doing what you are attempting.

Comment: Apparently those tools do not support PDFs encrypted with AES. E.g. pdftk is based on an iText version from times when integrated AES encryption of PDFs had not yet been specified.

Comment: Apache Tika can be told to ignore, follow or report on documents encrypted with the default password for the format, depending on the use case for the extraction (eg forensics, end-user or indexing)

Comment: I don't believe this document is encrypted.  It is compressed.

Comment: This is not a question of believe, you can simply verify it. It is encrypted using AES-128. (It also uses compression but which pdf nowadays doesn't...) By the way, you yourself mentioned the owner password. Passwords in pdfs only occur for encrypted pdfs...