# Unable to read contents of a particular page using PDFbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am unable to use setStartPage and setEndpage for a PDF that is downloaded from a particular link.It shows the entire content of the document and not the content from the particular page. But my code works for sample pdf downloaded from http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf.

```
    File file = new File(home + "/Downloads/" + fileDownloaded);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(fis);
    PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
    reader.setStartPage(1);
    reader.setEndPage(1);
    String pageText = reader.getText(pdfDoc);
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println(pageText);
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");`
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? The current version is 2.0.26. Your code looks ok and I understand your question. Btw (unrelated to your problem) you can open the file directly, you don't need `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I am using 2.0.24. Yes, that is correct. it works without FileInputStream. I tried using 2.0.26 but it still reads the entire content of the PDF. Is there any other solution to this? Also can some help me rephrase the question if it is not clear?

Comment: The PDF is generated using some internal tool, but does the origin of the PDF affect the use of PDFbox library? Also, what do I need to check in the PDF properties so that PDFbox can extract the content from the PDF?

Comment: The origin doesn't matter if the PDF is correct. I can only say that your PDF is fine and I was able to get the first page only with your code. Thus I suspect something went wrong when writing the question, this can happen when stressed. Re the second question, this is complex. Your file doesn't have permissions, so text extraction is allowed. But for extraction to actually work much more is to be done which is much too long to explain (but most files are fine, and so is yours).

Comment: So if I am getting it right, there is something wrong with that particular PDF I am using and nothing wrong with the code. Is there any alternative to PDFbox to extract content from the PDF that I can try?

Comment: No the PDF is fine. The one from the link. I suspect your code uses a different one.

Comment: Yes I am using different PDF, but I cannot share that PDF here. Anything that can help me debug or identify what's wrong with the PDF?

Comment: You can use PDFDebugger and look at the cropbox / mediabox of the pages. Sometimes PDFs (e.g. 3 part folded flyers) have the same page content but different cropbox / mediabox. So you see a different part each time, but text extraction doesn't take these into consideration.

Comment: Okay great, will check that.

Comment: Any suggestions or links on how to use PDFdebugger with Java maven project? or how to check the pages of the pdf using pdfdebugger?

Comment: PDFDebugger is an application. Download and run. Click everywhere.

Comment: *"Yes I am using different PDF, but I cannot share that PDF here. Anything that can help me debug or identify what's wrong with the PDF?"* - Without seeing the PDF we can only guess. One possible cause I've seen a number of times is that the content stream of each page contains the content of multiple pages and shows only one page by setting the crop box accordingly.

Comment: You can try the tool `ShowVicinity` used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68406240/1729265) that enlarges the media box and removes clip paths to check whether there are additional contents in the page content streams around the visual content.